# async queue doesn't go idle on kill

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, queue, async.js

I use the async library to manage my asyncronous requests in a web worker using the queue object.
But when i run the queue objects kill command it doesn't go into idle state oposing to the documentation that says:

> kill: a function that removes the drain callback and empties remaining
>   tasks from the queue forcing it to go idle. Invoke with queue.kill().

I want to stop the queue and kill the web worker when there is a error in one task. But i found out, that kill isn't finished when i call the message that tells my worker manager to kill this worker. Instead it infinitly tells me idle is false.

I use the following code:

```
var q = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
    FileReader.readBlock(task.file, task.offset, task.blockSize)
    .then(function(block) {
        return sendBlock(task.uuid, block, task.blockNumber);
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        callback(null, result);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        callback(error);
    });
}, 8);

q.drain = function() {
    console.log('All Tasks finished successfully.');
};

q.error = function(error, task) {
    this.kill();

    while(true) {
        if(this.idle()) {
            self.postMessage({
                type: 'error',
                msg: 'A task failed. Upload is killed.'
            });
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Is that a bug in async or is there a mistake on my part?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the version of the async library that you are using. The `error` callback was added in version 2.0.

If you are using version 1.5, you will need to handle errors in the callback you pass when adding a task to the queue. Adapted from the [docs](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#queue):

```
q.push({name: 'foo'}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // handle error here
      q.kill(); 
      // ... etc
    }
    console.log('finished processing foo');
});
```